# Swagger Whitelabel Error Page Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

after configure the swagger and run the application on Spring boot i ran in to the problem with

```
Whitelabel Error Page
```

what i tried so far i attached below.please correct this issues

**SwaggerConfig**

```
public Docket SwaggerApi()
{
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}


public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {


    //Swagger UI property
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: At least post a mapping which gives you a white label response :) 
Something like `/api/<v>/swagger-ui.html`? Springfox also tends to log the registered mappings, could be useful.